# Why is my Django login not getting authenticated?

Tags: django, django-login

I do know that this is a repeated question. I did refer those answers but still I couldn't get my issue fixed. Kindly do help. Registration works just fine. The registered users gets added to the DB fine. Logout works fine. The issue is with login. Whenever I try logging in , I keep getting the response "Invalid login details".

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . forms import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


# USER LOGIN

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user =authenticate( username=username, password=password)          

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account not active")

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details")    #whenever I try to login, I always gets this response.

    else:
        return render(request, 'basic_app/login.html')




#USER LOGOUT

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

urls.py(application).

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='home'),
    path('register/',views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/',views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class='jumbotron'>
    <h2>User Login</h2>

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password">

        <input type="submit" value="Login">

    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/basic_app/login/'
```

Comment: Can put print statement and print  `username , password ` 
before this line 
`user =authenticate( username=username, password=password)`
Check if you username and password from the form are vaild.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did put a print statement and I got "None None" in the console. Why am I not able to get the username and password? The users gets registered fine in the database. I am able to see their details through admin panel.

Comment: Try to put name attr in the template like this
`<input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">`

See if this works

Comment: `<input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password">`

Comment: Thanks a ton brother. I missed the name attribute in my input tags and that was causing the problem.

Comment: You can upvote the comment if it was helpful

Comment: Is it possible for me to upvote your comment ?. I couldn't find an option to do so. Otherwise I would've done it back then itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Make a copy of your Project in another folder. AND delete the current database and 
create a new Database as usual like :- IN Terminal - Create Superuser command is :- 
python manage.py createsuperuser.
```

Comment: As you said, I did create a new Database but I still keep getting that same response "Invalid login details". The registration works fine though.

Comment: Are you using custom sign up OR signup system is modified by you ?

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py, in the `user_login` function you are checking if the `user.is_active`.

Instead try checking if the user is ***authenticated*** in the if statement.

Because I think that the user would probably be inactive before being logged in or authenticated.

For example, this is from the documentation:

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Do something for authenticated users.
    ...
else:
    # Do something for anonymous users.
    ...
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

## Edit

Sorry, I was lookin at the wrong `if` block.

You don't seem to have assigned anything to the *user* variable. That maybe why the user is returned as none.

Also you can try:

`user = request.user`